# Generating script for full-text index has syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008 Management studio to generate full-text index. The script like:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[MyTable](
[ID] LANGUAGE [English], 
[Name] LANGUAGE [English], 
...
KEY INDEX [MyTable_PK]ON ([AMSFullTextSearchCatalog], FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
GO
```

Then I try to run this script and got error said:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

Not sure why. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you show the whole query please

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = SYSTEM)
```

with this:

```
WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM , CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO
```

This is the syntax they use on [MSDN's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx)